# Detecting use of register globals

Tags: php, code-analysis

Is there any way in PHP to do static code analysis and detect reliance on the `register_globals` initiative?  It's relatively straightforward to manually examine a file and look for variables which have not been initialized and infer from that that these may be relying on it, but I need to do this for many hundreds of scripts, so I'm looking for an automated solution.

My last resort is setting up a dev environment with the directive turned off and strict error reporting and letting QA play around for a long while, then fix the instances that the error log catches, but this is not guaranteed to find 100% of the cases, and certainly not a good use of resources if an automated solution exists.

Comment: It would be difficult because you would need to take into account variable variables and functions like `extract()`

Comment: I'm thinking "no". As @MikeB correctly points out, things like `extract()` and variable variables (and additionally `$GLOBALS`) throw a huge spanner in the works for any kind of code analysis that doesn't actually execute the code. Yes you can try running the scripts in a batch and look for complaints about the use of variables that are not set, but there's always the possibility that the code is just broken anyway (although I suppose in this case it still needs fixing). Unfortunately the manual approach is probably your only option here. Enjoy...

Comment: Be careful, `register_globals` was removed since PHP 5.4.0.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A small script I just hacked together to detect simple undefined variables. You'll need [PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) for this:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$dir = './foo';

require_once './lib/bootstrap.php';

class Scope {
    protected $stack;
    protected $pos;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->stack = array();
        $this->pos = -1;
    }

    public function addVar($name) {
        $this->stack[$this->pos][$name] = true;
    }

    public function hasVar($name) {
        return isset($this->stack[$this->pos][$name]);
    }

    public function pushScope() {
        $this->stack[++$this->pos] = array();
    }

    public function popScope() {
        --$this->pos;
    }
}

class UndefinedVariableVisitor extends PHPParser_NodeVisitorAbstract {
    protected $scope;
    protected $parser;
    protected $traverser;

    public function __construct(Scope $scope, PHPParser_Parser $parser, PHPParser_NodeTraverser $traverser) {
        $this->scope = $scope;
        $this->parser = $parser;
        $this->traverser = $traverser;
    }

    public function enterNode(PHPParser_Node $node) {
        if (($node instanceof PHPParser_Node_Expr_Assign || $node instanceof PHPParser_Node_Expr_AssignRef)
            && $node->var instanceof PHPParser_Node_Expr_Variable
            && is_string($node->var->name)
        ) {
            $this->scope->addVar($node->var->name);
        } elseif ($node instanceof PHPParser_Node_Stmt_Global || $node instanceof PHPParser_Node_Stmt_Static) {
            foreach ($node->vars as $var) {
                if (is_string($var->name)) {
                    $this->scope->addVar($var->name);
                }
            }
        } elseif ($node instanceof PHPParser_Node_Expr_Variable && is_string($node->name)) {
            if (!$this->scope->hasVar($node->name)) {
                echo 'Undefined variable $' . $node->name . ' on line ' . $node->getLine() . "\n";
            }
        } elseif ($node instanceof PHPParser_Node_Stmt_Function || $node instanceof PHPParser_Node_Stmt_ClassMethod) {
            $this->scope->pushScope();

            // params are always available
            foreach ($node->params as $param) {
                $this->scope->addVar($param->name);
            }

            // methods always have $this
            if ($node instanceof PHPParser_Node_Stmt_ClassMethod) {
                $this->scope->addVar('this');
            }
        } elseif ($node instanceof PHPParser_Node_Expr_Include && $node->expr instanceof PHPParser_Node_Scalar_String) {
            $file = $node->expr->value;
            $code = file_get_contents($file);
            $stmts = $this->parser->parse($code);

            // for includes within the file
            $cwd = getcwd();
            chdir(dirname($file));

            $this->traverser->traverse($stmts);

            chdir($cwd);
        }
    }

    public function leaveNode(PHPParser_Node $node) {
        if ($node instanceof PHPParser_Node_Stmt_Function || $node instanceof PHPParser_Node_Stmt_ClassMethod) {
            $this->scope->popScope();
        }
    }
}

$parser = new PHPParser_Parser(new PHPParser_Lexer());

$scope = new Scope;

$traverser = new PHPParser_NodeTraverser;
$traverser->addVisitor(new UndefinedVariableVisitor($scope, $parser, $traverser));

foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
             new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir),
             RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY)
         as $file
) {
    if (!preg_match('/\.php$/', $file)) continue;

    echo 'Checking ' . $file . ':', "\n";

    $code = file_get_contents($file);
    $stmts = $parser->parse($code);

    // for includes within the file
    $cwd = getcwd();
    chdir(dirname($file));

    $scope->pushScope();
    $traverser->traverse($stmts);
    $scope->popScope();

    chdir($cwd);

    echo "\n";
}
```

It's just a very basic implementation and I did not test it extensively, but it should work for scripts that don't go wild with `$GLOBALS` and `$$varVars`. It does basic include resolution.

Comment: Just an FYI, in an Apache environment `if (!preg_match('/\.php$/', $file)) continue;` is not fool proof. Apache will execute anything that matches `/\.php(\.|$)/` as a PHP script (and that would have an `i` modifier on Windows). This is a little-known bit of Apache weirdness that accounts for many, many security holes in the world of PHP powered sites. This looks like it *probably* deserves a +1, although I can't say I know enough about what it (specifically `PHPParser`) is doing to give you one without feeling like I'm upvoting stuff I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (from one of the php manual comments):

```
if (ini_get('register_globals')) {
    foreach ($GLOBALS as $int_temp_name => $int_temp_value) {
        if (!in_array($int_temp_name, array (
                'GLOBALS',
                '_FILES',
                '_REQUEST',
                '_COOKIE',
                '_SERVER',
                '_ENV',
                '_SESSION',
                ini_get('session.name'),
                'int_temp_name',
                'int_temp_value'
            ))) {
            unset ($GLOBALS[$int_temp_name]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How will this statically detect the use of globals?

Comment: Yes, or you *could* just turn `register_globals` off. But the OP is asking if it's possible to programmatically detect whether a script expects it to be turned on, not how to mimic it being turned off. Plus that doesn't catch many of the variables that *might* be turned on in various situations. What about `$argv`? What about `$argc`? What about `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`?

Answer (score 0):

Tweaked the code above with the latest parser: used it to make 5.4 register_globals to 7.2

```
    <?php
/*
 * pgParser.php is a "Abstract syntax tree" progam based on the Nikic PHP-Parser  https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser
 * Tweaked for use to lose register global variables.
 */

use PhpParser\Node;
use PhpParser\NodeTraverser;
use PhpParser\NodeVisitorAbstract;
use PhpParser\Parser;

error_reporting(E_ALL);

/*
 * $dir contains a base dir to use when no PARAM directory eq "php ./pgParser.php /home/hrobben/php/ > results.txt"
 */
$dir = '/home/hrobben/php/';
/*
 * $nonecheck : variables not to check....
 * e.g ['GLOBALS','_COOKIE', 'properties'] -> $GLOBALS, $_COOKIE, $properties >>>>> will not been checked.
 */
$nonecheck = ['_COOKIE', '_SERVER', '_SESSION'];
/*
 * if those names part or directory not include...
 * this can be usefull when certain users (developers) have own directories
 * empty = [] no directories will be excluded
 * e.g. ['george', 'henry']  all directories /tree/git/base/src/henry/  and /template/george/blog/  will be excluded.
 */
$nonesubdir = ['henry', 'ckeditor'];
/*
 * $excludeMatch can be filled with text in directory plus file to exclude.
 * e.q.  _MA. will exclude the file index_MA.php3 to scan.
 * e.g.  _MA will exclude the file /git/src/test_MAIN/index.php3
 * be carefull.
 * Not for include files, only base files.
 */
$excludeMatch = ['_HR.', '_ed.'];
/*
 * you can give a base directory to begin scanning.
 */
if (count($argv) > 0) {
    $dir = $argv[1];
}

require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

class Scope
{
    protected $stack;
    protected $pos;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->stack = array();
        $this->pos = -1;
    }

    public function addVar($name)
    {
        $this->stack[$this->pos][$name] = true;
    }

    public function hasVar($name): bool
    {
        return isset($this->stack[$this->pos][$name]);
    }

    public function pushScope()
    {
        $this->stack[++$this->pos] = array();
    }

    public function popScope()
    {
        --$this->pos;
    }

    public function getPos()
    {
        return $this->pos;
    }
}

class UndefinedVariableVisitor extends NodeVisitorAbstract
{
    protected $scope;
    protected $parser;
    protected $traverser;
    protected $nonecheck;
    protected $isInclude = false;

    public function __construct(Scope $scope, Parser $parser, NodeTraverser $traverser, array $nonecheck)
    {
        $this->scope = $scope;
        $this->parser = $parser;
        $this->traverser = $traverser;
        $this->nonecheck = $nonecheck;
    }

    public function enterNode(Node $node)
    {
        $includePath = ['/home/hrobben/php/include/class/'];
        $nonesubdir = ['jp', 'jp117']; // for the include exclusion directories.

        if (($node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Expr\Assign || $node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Expr\AssignRef)
            && $node->var instanceof PhpParser\Node\Expr\Variable
            && is_string($node->var->name)
        ) {
            // if preg_replace uses the same var name as second argument, its not setting a var, it must also be on the first level.
            if ($node->expr->name->parts[0] == 'preg_replace' && $node->expr->args[2]->value->name == $node->var->name && $this->scope->getPos() == 0) {
                //echo 'found $'.$node->expr->args[2]->value->name.' level '.$this->scope->getPos()."\n";
            } else {
                //echo 'add var $' . $node->var->name . "\n";
                $this->scope->addVar($node->var->name);
            }
        } elseif ($node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Stmt\Global_ || $node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Stmt\Static_) {
            foreach ($node->vars as $var) {
                if (is_string($var->name)) {
                    $this->scope->addVar($var->name);
                    //echo 'add global or static var $' . $var->name . "\n";
                }
            }
        } elseif ($node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Stmt\Foreach_) {
            $this->scope->addVar($node->valueVar->name);
            if ($node->keyVar) {
                $this->scope->addVar($node->keyVar->name);
            }
        } elseif ($node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Stmt\StaticVar) {
            $this->scope->addVar($node->var->name);
        } elseif ($node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Expr\FuncCall && ($node->name->parts[0] == 'preg_match')) {
            foreach ($node->args as $args) {
                if ($node->args[2]) {
                    $this->scope->addVar($node->args[2]->value->name);
                }
            }
        } elseif ($node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Expr\List_) {
            foreach ($node->items as $item) {
                $this->scope->addVar($item->value->name);
            }
        } elseif ($node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Expr\Closure) {
            foreach ($node->params as $param) {
                $this->scope->addVar($param->var->name);
            }
        } elseif ($node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Expr\Variable && is_string($node->name) && !$node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Const_) {
            if (!$this->scope->hasVar($node->name) && !in_array($node->name, $this->nonecheck)) {
                echo 'Undefined variable $' . $node->name . ' on line ' . $node->getLine() . "\n";
            }
        } elseif ($node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Stmt\Function_ || $node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Stmt\ClassMethod) {
            $this->scope->pushScope();

            // params are always available
            foreach ($node->params as $param) {
                //echo 'param name : '. $param->var->name. "\n";
                $this->scope->addVar($param->var->name);
            }

            // methods always have $this
            if ($node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Stmt\ClassMethod) {
                $this->scope->addVar('this');
            }
        } elseif ($node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Expr\Include_ && $node->expr instanceof PhpParser\Node\Scalar\String_) {
            $file = $node->expr->value;

            $code = file_get_contents($file);
            if (strlen($code) < 5) {
                foreach ($includePath as $path) {
                    if (strlen($code) < 5) {
                        $code = file_get_contents($path . $file);
                    }
                }
            }

            $match_string = implode("\/|", $nonesubdir);
            if (preg_match("/$match_string\//", $file)) {
                $code = '';
                echo 'file skipped: ' . $file . "\n";
            }

            $stmts = $this->parser->parse($code);
            // for includes within the file
            $cwd = getcwd();
            chdir(dirname($file));

            $this->isInclude = true;
            $this->traverser->traverse($stmts);
            $this->isInclude = false;

            chdir($cwd);
            if (strlen($code) < 5) {
                echo 'Include <- ' . $file . ' not found or empty.' . "\n";
            } else {
                echo 'Include <- ' . $file . "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    public function leaveNode(Node $node)
    {
        if ($node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Stmt\Function_ || $node instanceof PhpParser\Node\Stmt\ClassMethod) {
            $this->scope->popScope();
        }
    }
}

$lexer = new PhpParser\Lexer();
$parser = (new PhpParser\ParserFactory)->create(
    PhpParser\ParserFactory::PREFER_PHP7,
    $lexer
);

$scope = new Scope;

$traverser = new NodeTraverser();
$traverser->addVisitor(new UndefinedVariableVisitor($scope, $parser, $traverser, $nonecheck));

foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
             new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir),
             RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY)
         as $file
) {
    if (!preg_match('/\.php$|\.html$|\.php3$/', $file)) continue;

    $match_string = implode("\/|\/", $nonesubdir);
    if (preg_match("/\/$match_string\//", $file)) continue;

    $match_string = implode("|", $excludeMatch);
    if (preg_match("/$match_string/", $file)) continue;

    echo 'Checking ' . $file . ':', "\n";

    $code = file_get_contents($file);
    $stmts = $parser->parse($code);
    // print_r($stmts);
    // for includes within the file
    $cwd = getcwd();
    chdir(dirname($file));

    $scope->pushScope();
    $traverser->traverse($stmts);
    //print_r($stmts);
    $scope->popScope();

    chdir($cwd);

    echo "\n";
}
```

Used this to make a big many script files holding code to go without global registered variables. We gone use it with PHP7.2